# isinstance(datetime.datetime, DateTimeField.value) always returns false for Django DateTimeField

Tags: python, django, datetime, xlsxwriter

I think there is probably something very simple I'm missing here but I can't find it.

I have a custom admin command in my django project that should iterate through instances of a `Record`'s model and write them to an xlsx file.

I am using `xlsxwriter`, and as a result, I need to convert the `datetime.datetime` values in the `Record` instances to naive objects. So I want to say "When you encounter a `DateTimeField` in the `Record` model use `value.replace(tzinfo=None)` to make the object naive before writing it".

For some reason, my `if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime)` is never returning true and I get a write error from `xlsxwriter` about the naive/aware `datetime` object.

Here is the relevant code:

sampleadmincommand.py

```
import pytz
import datetime
....
for i, row in enumerate(list(Record.objects.all())):

    for j,field in enumerate(list(Record._meta.get_fields())):
            value = getattr(row,field.name)
            if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                value.replace(tzinfo=None)
                worksheet.write(i, j, value)

            else:
                worksheet.write(i, j, value)
```

models.py

```
class Record(models.Model):

    time = models.DateTimeField()
    manHoursScheduled = models.FloatField()
    manHoursWorked = models.FloatField()
    carsOvernight = models.IntegerField()
    carsEvent = models.IntegerField()
    dailyTransientIncome = models.FloatField()
    dailyTransientCars = models.FloatField()
    dailyTransientIncomePerCar = models.FloatField()

    nightlyTransientIncome = models.FloatField(null=True)
    nightlyTransientIncomePerCar = models.FloatField(null=True)

    eventName = models.TextField(null=True)

    facility = models.ForeignKey(Facility)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.facility.name
```

I'm pretty stumped as to what I'm doing wrong here, so I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Apologies, that has to do with my paste. The indentation is all correct, I've edited the post to show as much.

Comment: @JwM I did  few edits too.

Comment: Where is your check?

Comment: It's located in the second for-loop of the admin command. I was messing around with different checks before I copied the code and forgot to change it back. Fixed.

Comment: Hm. I tried it and it still did not trigger the statement. You may be on to something though, I'm going to mess with it a bit more.

Comment: @JwM Which Django version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.8.3. For now I think I'll just set Django's timezone to UTC to get around this issue.

Comment: @JohnPirie no. The field class is only used in the metaclass, not in the instance. The value of a field of type DateTimeField should indeed be of type datetime.datetime.

Comment: Have you considered using a try/except instead of `isinstance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It seems you have missed assigning the naive datetime object back to the `value` datetime object.**

It should be

```
value = value.replace(tzinfo=None) # assign 'naive' datetime object back to 'value'
```

instead of just

```
value.replace(tzinfo=None) # will just return 'naive' datetime object
```

The code now becomes:

```
import pytz
import datetime
....
for i, row in enumerate(list(Record.objects.all())):

    for j,field in enumerate(list(Record._meta.get_fields())):
            value = getattr(row,field.name)
            if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
                value = value.replace(tzinfo=None) # assign value as 'naive' datetime object 
                worksheet.write(i, j, value) # will now use 'naive' datetime object to write

            else:
                worksheet.write(i, j, value)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly my problem, I can't believe I missed something so simple.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not answered yet, your code always returns false because instead of using DateTimeField of django model you are using datetime.datetime

so insted of using:

```
if isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
```

you should do:

```
from django.db.models.fields import DateTimeField
if isinstance(value, DateTimeField):
```